# Select Column, Count(Column) but order by a third column value

Tags: sql

I tryed to do what was on this thread: [SELECT COUNT messes with ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285110/select-count-messes-with-order-by)

But It seemed that I can't use the solution in ASP cshtml (or don't know how).

Here is the code I have right now

```
var selectCommand3 = "SELECT Ident, COUNT(Ident) As Column1 FROM ToolDor_AppMagDor AS NumberOfOrders GROUP BY Ident"; 
var selectedData3 = db.Query(selectCommand3);
```

What I would like to do is order By DateCR. A third column where the DateCR column value is the same for each Ident column value. Like if there is 10 rows with the same Ident, the DateCR will also be the same.

I can't just Select DateCR instead because there can be more than one different Ident value for one DateCR...

I tryed a substring index but I dont seem to be able to make it works.

Basicaly I would like the system to accept this (but it won't =P) :

```
var selectCommand3 = "SELECT Ident, COUNT(Ident) As Column1 FROM ToolDor_AppMagDor AS NumberOfOrders GROUP BY Ident ORDER By DateCR DESC"; 
var selectedData3 = db.Query(selectCommand3);
```

Thank you for your help and sorry for my english

Comment: You can't `ORDER BY` `DateCR` because it doesn't exist in your result set. You may be able to get what you need by using a `COUNT()...OVER()...` and `SELECTING` `Ident` and `DateCR`, then whittling down your results. Can you put together a simple example of your data that you're working with?

Comment: Can you do `SELECT Ident, DateCR, count(Ident) AS Column1 FROM ToolDor_AppMagDot GROUP BY Ident, DateCR ORDER BY DateCR DESC`? I dropped your alias for the ToolDor_AppMagDor table, since it isn't being used in this query.

Comment: Thank you Shawn, Gordon answered it, but to answer your second question, no it was saying that DateCR wasn't contain in an aggregated function or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an aggregation function on the column, because the `ORDER BY` is processed *after* the aggregation.

This probably does what you want:

```
SELECT Ident, COUNT(Ident) As Column1
FROM ToolDor_AppMagDor NumberOfOrders
GROUP BY Ident
ORDER By MAX(DateCR) DESC;
```

Comment: Are you kidding me?! #?&! I got the feeling my question will be downvoted but thank you very much. I was looking so far away!